# Passing json via command prompt

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, command, prompt

I pass the following json via command prompt as

```
$python new.py {'scenarioId':'null','scenarioName':'EC_02','scenarioDesc':'EC_02','riskEngine':'null'}
```

and when I run the following:

```
import sys
import json
str_json = sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"')

try:
    d = json.dumps(str_json)
    dat = json.loads(b)
    print("Stress JSON is as follows \n",dat)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Not a valid JSON")

print(dat['scenarioId'])
```

It's a valid json but I get the error **TypeError: string indices must be integers** for the last line. 
It works fine when I initialize it as str_json in the code itself.
How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you dump and load the data again, twice?

Answer (score 0):

In your code when you are using `a_json = json.loads(b)`, here type of `b` variable is still string, convert it into json: `a_json = json.loads(json.loads(b))`

Code:

```
import sys
import json
str_json = sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"')
try:
    b = json.dumps(str_json)
    a_json = json.loads(json.loads(b))
    print("Stress JSON is as follows \n",a_json)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Not a valid JSON")


print(a_json['scenarioId'])
```

Output:

```
Stress JSON is as follows 
 {'scenarioId': 'null', 'scenarioName': 'EC_02', 'scenarioDesc': 'EC_02', 'riskEngine': 'null'}
null
```

Comment: @KeyurPethad Is this answer helpful?

Comment: Got this error    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data::

Comment: @KeyurPethad are you passing the same input which you mentioned in question?I am getting proper output when I passed the input from your question

Comment: ohh.. great now you edited your code, first make sure what you want to ask

Comment: Yes I passed the same input. Edited the code as it was redundant as pointed out by Klaus. Let me check again.. Thanks